# Testcase level variables in [Documentation] for robot framework

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I cannot get test level variables to appear in documentation.

Let's say I have this testsuite:

```
| *Variables* |
| ${SystemUnderTest} = | Staging

| *testcase* |
| Device Test |
| | Set Test Variable   | ${device}      | iPhone
| | [Documentation]     |  Device is: ${device} |
| | ...                 |  System is: ${SystemUnderTest} |
| | No Operation
```

That produces this log:

```
TEST CASE: Device TestExpand All
Full Name:  T.Device Test
Documentation:  
Device is: ${device} System is: Staging
```

Notice that the Suite level variable is treated properly, but the test level one is not.
How do I get all variables to be treated equally?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the documentation part is processed before anything else in the test case. This includes any kind of command that would set a variable. I tried to check if the Test Setup would do the trick, but it seems that even the test setup is run after the documentation part of the test case... and so the results are the same...

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Being able to do this would simplify a number of my tests.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with robotframework 2.7 there is a built-in keyword named `Set test documentation`, which can be used to replace or append to the existing documentation. This will *not* affect the output in the console, but the changes *will* be reflected in the log and report.

For example:

```
| *Variables* |
| ${SystemUnderTest} = | Staging

| *testcase* |
| Device Test |
| | Set Test Variable   | ${device}      | iPhone
| | [Documentation]     |  Device is: ${device} |
| | ...                 |  System is: ${SystemUnderTest} |
| | Substitute vars in documentation
| | No Operation

| *Keywords* |
| Substitute vars in documentation
| | ${doc}= | replace variables | ${test documentation}
| | set test documentation | ${doc}
```

For more information see http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.7.7#Set%20Test%20Documentation

Comment: Well, that is something.  Still would be nice to be able to keep track of things in console. Thanks

Comment: Useful, but without being able to output to the console not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This solution feels a little hackerish to me, but it does give you the functionality that you want.

### Test.txt

```
| *Setting*   | *Value*            |
              # This should start as the value for your first test
| Suite Setup | Set Suite Variable | ${device} | foo

| *Test Case* | *Action* | *Argument*
#
| T100 | [Documentation] | Should be foo: ${device}
       # Do some stuff
|      | No Operation
       # This setups the device name for the next test.
|      | Set Suite Variable | ${device} | bar 
#
| T101 | [Documentation] | Should be bar: ${device}
       # Do some stuff
|      | No Operation
|      | Set Suite Variable | ${device} | bing
#
| T102 | [Documentation] | Should be bing: ${device}
       # Do some stuff
|      | No Operation
```

When I run the suite I get this output:

```
==============================================================================
Test                                                                          
==============================================================================
T100 :: Should be foo: foo                                            | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T101 :: Should be bar: bar                                            | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T102 :: Should be bing: bing                                          | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | PASS |
3 critical tests, 3 passed, 0 failed
3 tests total, 3 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Having the device variable set at the end of the previous test is a little unclean, but as long you leave a comment it shouldn't be unclear at all.