# Robot Framework Set test documentation multiline

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, selenium2library

I would like use KW "Set test documentation" with multiline with RobotFW
The return to the line (\n) does not work with this KW

Someone have solution?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use [Documentation] tag with multiline started as ... ?

Comment: Ye because i have some variables in my TC, i need to display them in Documentation with Set test documentation

Comment: please show what you've tried.

Comment: For one TC i have 3 or 4 custom KW. In my KWs i have some dynamic var. I want displayed with multiline in documentation all my var

Comment: @Antho03 can you show us your 'code' i.e. the documentation text you want to have formatted and what it looks with how you tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting multiline documentation is tricky because robot has some odd rules about its documentation. From the user guide section titled [Documentation Formatting](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#documentation-formatting):

> Starting from Robot Framework 2.7.2, all regular text in the formatted HTML documentation is represented as paragraphs. In practice, lines separated by a single newline will be combined in a paragraph regardless whether the newline is added manually or automatically. **Multiple paragraphs can be separated with an empty line (i.e. two newlines)** and also tables, lists, and other specially formatted blocks discussed in subsequent sections end a paragraph.

In a nutshell, that means that each line needs to end with two newlines.

Example:

```
*** Variables ***
${var1}  this is var1
${var2}  this is var2

*** Test Cases ***
Example of setting multiline test documentation
    set test documentation
    ...  var1: ${var1}\n\nvar2: ${var2}
```

The above will appear in log.html like this:

[image: robot log.html test documentation with multiple lines]

If your goal is to document the values of variables, robot also supports a simple markup for creating tables. The following example shows how to create a table. In this example I use the ability to append to the documentation rather than replace it:

```
*** Variables ***
${var1}  this is var1
${var2}  this is var2

*** Test Cases ***

Example 2: documentation with embedded table
    set test documentation  
    ...  | var1 | ${var1} | \n
    set test documentation
    ...  | var2 | ${var2} | \n  append=True
```

The above will appear in log.html like this:

[image: robot log.html test documentation with embedded table]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we can do that directly, i found a workaround   after taking reference from Bryan's reply on this thread.

[Testcase level variables in [Documentation] for robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752796/testcase-level-variables-in-documentation-for-robot-framework)

Here multi lines are first mentioned in [Documentation] section and then this section can be used by Set test documentation kw.

```
*** Variables***
${SystemUnderTest}    Staging

*** Test cases***
Device Test
    Set Test Variable   ${device}    iPhone
    [Documentation]     Device is:
    ...                   System is: ${SystemUnderTest}
    Substitute vars in documentation


*** Keywords ***
Substitute vars in documentation
    ${doc}=  replace variables    ${test documentation}   # This will substitute the variables in documentation with their values , ${test documentation} is an inbuilt keyword which actually parse the content of [Documentation]
    set test documentation    ${doc}    append=True    #now the set test docuemntation will take the multi line input from documentation section
```

refer below link for further details http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Documentation

Comment: I dont understand how display several var with multiline with this method My var are in a lot of keywords for ONE TC ... I need see for this TC all my Var with multiline

Comment: please edit your question and add some code, its difficult to understand what you are trying to say